# Ten years later: How do I NOW mount my Android phone?

Tags: mount, android, mtp

Please note: I'm only asking because I'm lacking TEN "reputation points" in THIS Stack-Exchange venue as otherwise I'd have posted a modern answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297766/how-do-i-mount-my-android-phone) (As an aside, PERHAPS the algorithm should consider reputations at affiliated stack-exchange venues?)

All I want and need to do is `mount` an `Android` phone on a modern installation (in this case `Fedora` 38, but there IS NO `Fedora` stack-exchange venue, and this ubuntu community seems to be taking up the slack quite readily)...

NONE of the answers there worked for me. And, I spent HOURS trying.

Comment: You can post Fedora questions on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

1. Install `mtpfs`, or `jmtpfs`, depending on your distribution.
2. Create a mount point (ie: `mkdir` -somewhere- )
3. Mount the phone with the appropriate mount-command for your distribution.

In my case, I was frustrated that I was pointed somewhere to use `fusermount` as the mount-command I wanted, but it WOULD NOT WORK, complaining:

```
fusermount: old style mounting not supported
```

I then, on a lark, tried:

```
jmtpfs /media/phone0
```

and it worked!

Later, I tried unmounting with:

```
jmtpfs -u /media/phone0
```

And that worked, too!

Comment: Do we need to connect the phone using a USB cable, or does it work over the network? Also, to limit the answer to Ubuntu (and keeping it ontopic), `mtpfs` is not available on modern Ubuntu systems, but `jmptfs` is.

Comment: @Jos Hi Jos, just noticed your comment: I only tried USB cable attached phones, so I can't answer your question. And thanks for informing that jmptfs IS available on Ubuntu!